# Maven - multi module project for spring boot war and uber jar project

Tags: maven, spring-boot, maven-plugin

I am trying to create multi module spring boot application where structure of current application is like

```
parent build Pom
   |
   |-----------Core module jar packaging
   |
   |-----------Uber jar (simple module with core module jar as dependency)
   |
   |----------War file (simple module with core module jar as dependency)
```

However due to this war file is created with original core module in lib folder and there is nothing preset in web-inf classes folder.

Does anyone knows how it can be achieve ?